# Is JASA documentclass not working?

Tags: document-classes

I have the following "minimal example" which is not working:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[preprint]{JASA}


\begin{document}

    \title{My Title}
    \author{My Name}

\begin{abstract}
My abstract
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

My paper starts here\ldots

\end{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

I am using MikTeX 2.9 perfectly updated on a Win10 machine and I just downloaded the documentclass from JASA website: https://asa.scitation.org/jas/authors/manuscript

[Click here](https://asa.scitation.org/jas/authors/manuscript)

Everything would work OK until a couple of months ago (after that I had routine updates of the packages installed on my MikTeX system....)

The first time a ran this a few days ago the compiler stopped asking me about a

revtex4-1.cls

which was no longer on my system. I checked on CTAN and I saw that it is now considered to be obsolete (they have revtex4-2.cls now, it seems). Indeed on my MikTeX installation I had revtex4-2.cls  but NO LONGER any revtex4-1.cls (deleted by the package manager during un update?)

I wrote to the editorial office of the journal and they told me that I should install manually revtex4-1.cls. I did that but the system now stops complaining that:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    ! Extra \endgroup.
\savedocument ->\endgroup 
                          \document@inithook \true@sw {}\UseOneTimeHook {beg...
l.4 \begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

If I keep hittig the return key I do get a pdf output which has words

```
begindocument/before
```

on the top left of the first page.

What is the meaning of this?

The .log file is listed here below.

Does anyone have an opinion?

Thanks,
Maurizio

START OF .LOG FILE:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 20.11) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.11.17)  17 NOV 2020 09:25
entering extended mode
**./Test_JASA.tex
(Test_JASA.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-10-27> xparse <2020-03-03> (JASA.cls
Document Class: JASA 2019/09/09 Version 1.1, document class
Class JASA Info: 
 Written by Amy Hendrickson, amyh@texnology.com, http://www.texnology.com 
 
  on input line 93.
(C:\Users\Vianello\localtexmf\tex/Latex/revtex\revtex4-1.cls
Document Class: revtex4-1 2010/07/25/20:33:00 4.1r (http://publish.aps.org/revt
ex4/ for documentation)
 Copyright (c) 2009 The American Physical Society.
 mailto:revtex@aps.org
 Licensed under the LPPL:
http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/base/lppl.txt
 Arthur Ogawa <arthur_ogawa at sbcglobal dot net>
 Based on work by David Carlisle <david at dcarlisle.demon.co.uk>.
ltxutil[2010/07/25/20:33:00 4.1r utilities package (portions licensed from W. E
. Baxter web at superscript.com)]
LaTeX Info: Redefining \@centercr on input line 308.
Class revtex4-1 Info: Repairing broken LaTeX eqnarray on input line 358.
\eqncolsep=\skip47
Class revtex4-1 Info: Repairing hyperref-unfriendly LaTeX definition of \mpfoot
note on input line 433.
Class revtex4-1 Info: Repairing broken LateX \@sect on input line 755.
\intertabularlinepenalty=\count175
\@tbpen=\count176
\@arstrutbox@hline=\box47
Class revtex4-1 Info: Repairing broken LaTeX \@xbitor on input line 1786.
ltxfront[2010/07/25/20:33:00 4.1r frontmatter package (AO,DPC)]
\c@affil=\count177
\c@collab=\count178
\absbox=\box48
ltxgrid[2010/07/25/20:33:00 4.1r page grid package (portions licensed from W. E
. Baxter web at superscript.com)]
\c@linecount=\count179
\output@latex=\toks15
\box@size@1=\box49
\box@size@2=\box50
\@protection@box=\box51
\@topmark@saved=\toks16
\footins@saved=\box52
\footins@recovered=\box53
\column@recovered=\box54
\pagesofar=\box55
\footsofar=\box56
\pagegrid@col=\count180

Class revtex4-1 Warning: Failed to recognize \@vspace, \@vspacer, \@no@pgbk, \@
newline, and \\; no patches applied. Please get a more up-to-date class, .

\c@part=\count181
\c@section=\count182
\c@subsection=\count183
\c@subsubsection=\count184
\c@paragraph=\count185
\c@subparagraph=\count186
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\c@figure=\count187
\fbox@1=\box57
\c@table=\count188
\fbox@2=\box58
\c@video=\count189
\fbox@4=\box59
\@bibdataout=\write3
\widetext@top=\box60
\widetext@bot=\box61
Class revtex4-1 Info: Selecting society aip on input line 7542.
(C:\Users\Vianello\localtexmf\tex/Latex/revtex\aip4-1.rtx
File: aip4-1.rtx 2010/07/25 4.1r AIP substyle for REVTeX
Class revtex4-1 Info: RevTeX society AIP selected on input line 67.
)

Class revtex4-1 Warning: No journal specified, using default cha.

Using journal substyle cha.
Class revtex4-1 Info: Reading file aps12pt4-1.rtx on input line 7547.
(C:\Users\Vianello\localtexmf\tex/Latex/revtex\aps12pt4-1.rtx
File: aps12pt4-1 2010/07/25/20:33:00 4.1r (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for 
documentation)
Class revtex4-1 Info: RevTeX pointsize 12pt selected on input line 30.
)
Class revtex4-1 Info: Overriding 12pt on input line 7547.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/textcase\textcase.sty"
Package: textcase 2019/09/14 v1.00 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\amssymb.sty"
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\amsfonts.sty"
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\@emptytoks=\toks17
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty"
Package: amsmath 2020/09/23 v2.17i AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip50

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty"
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty"
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks18
\ex@=\dimen138
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \text on input line 28.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty"
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen139
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty"
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count190
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count191
\leftroot@=\count192
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
\classnum@=\count193
\DOTSCASE@=\count194
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box62
\strutbox@=\box63
\big@size=\dimen140
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count195
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count196
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count197
\dspbrk@lvl=\count198
\tag@help=\toks19
\row@=\count199
\column@=\count266
\maxfields@=\count267
\andhelp@=\toks20
\eqnshift@=\dimen141
\alignsep@=\dimen142
\tagshift@=\dimen143
\tagwidth@=\dimen144
\totwidth@=\dimen145
\lineht@=\dimen146
\@envbody=\toks21
\multlinegap=\skip51
\multlinetaggap=\skip52
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks22
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2923.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2924.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/url\url.sty"
\Urlmuskip=\muskip17
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/natbib\natbib.sty"
Package: natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
\bibhang=\skip53
\bibsep=\skip54
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 694.
\c@NAT@ctr=\count268
)
Class revtex4-1 Info: Repairing natbib's \BibitemShut on input line 7549.

(C:\Users\Vianello\localtexmf\tex/Latex/revtex\revsymb4-1.sty
Package: revsymb4-1 2010/07/25/20:33:00 4.1r (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ f
or documentation)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frak on input line 95.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Bbb on input line 111.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \REV@mathfrak on input line 119.
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2020/09/09 v1.2b Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks23
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2020/08/30 v1.4c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 105.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def"
File: pdftex.def 2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen147
\Gin@req@width=\dimen148
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/tools\dcolumn.sty"
Package: dcolumn 2014/10/28 v1.06 decimal alignment package (DPC)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/tools\array.sty"
Package: array 2019/08/31 v2.4l Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen149
\ar@mcellbox=\box64
\extrarowheight=\dimen150
\NC@list=\toks24
\extratabsurround=\skip55
\backup@length=\skip56
\ar@cellbox=\box65
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/tools\bm.sty"
Package: bm 2019/07/24 v1.2d Bold Symbol Support (DPC/FMi)
\symboldoperators=\mathgroup6
\symboldletters=\mathgroup7
\symboldsymbols=\mathgroup8
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathbf on input line 141.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bm on input line 209.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\latexsym.sty"
Package: latexsym 1998/08/17 v2.2e Standard LaTeX package (lasy symbols)
\symlasy=\mathgroup9
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `lasy' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/lasy/m/n --> U/lasy/b/n on input line 52.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/lineno\lineno.sty"
Package: lineno 2005/11/02 line numbers on paragraphs v4.41
\linenopenalty=\count269
\output=\toks25
\linenoprevgraf=\count270
\linenumbersep=\dimen151
\linenumberwidth=\dimen152
\c@linenumber=\count271
\c@pagewiselinenumber=\count272
\c@LN@truepage=\count273
\c@internallinenumber=\count274
\c@internallinenumbers=\count275
\quotelinenumbersep=\dimen153
\bframerule=\dimen154
\bframesep=\dimen155
\bframebox=\box66
LaTeX Info: Redefining \\ on input line 3056.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/adjustbox\adjustbox.sty"
Package: adjustbox 2020/08/19 v1.3 Adjusting TeX boxes (trim, clip, ...)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.sty"
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkeyval.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkvutils.tex"
\XKV@toks=\toks26
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks27
)
\XKV@depth=\count276
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/adjustbox\adjcalc.sty"
Package: adjcalc 2012/05/16 v1.1 Provides advanced setlength with multiple back
-ends (calc, etex, pgfmath)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/adjustbox\trimclip.sty"
Package: trimclip 2020/08/19 v1.2 Trim and clip general TeX material

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/collectbox\collectbox.sty"
Package: collectbox 2012/05/17 v0.4b Collect macro arguments as boxes
\collectedbox=\box67
)
\tc@llx=\dimen156
\tc@lly=\dimen157
\tc@urx=\dimen158
\tc@ury=\dimen159
Package trimclip Info: Using driver 'tc-pdftex.def'.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/adjustbox\tc-pdftex.def"
File: tc-pdftex.def 2019/01/04 v2.2 Clipping driver for pdftex
))
\adjbox@Width=\dimen160
\adjbox@Height=\dimen161
\adjbox@Depth=\dimen162
\adjbox@Totalheight=\dimen163
\adjbox@pwidth=\dimen164
\adjbox@pheight=\dimen165
\adjbox@pdepth=\dimen166
\adjbox@ptotalheight=\dimen167

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/ifoddpage\ifoddpage.sty"
Package: ifoddpage 2016/04/23 v1.1 Conditionals for odd/even page detection
\c@checkoddpage=\count277
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/varwidth\varwidth.sty"
Package: varwidth 2009/03/30 ver 0.92;  Variable-width minipages
\@vwid@box=\box68
\sift@deathcycles=\count278
\@vwid@loff=\dimen168
\@vwid@roff=\dimen169
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/ulem\ulem.sty"
\UL@box=\box69
\UL@hyphenbox=\box70
\UL@skip=\skip57
\UL@hook=\toks28
\UL@height=\dimen170
\UL@pe=\count279
\UL@pixel=\dimen171
\ULC@box=\box71
Package: ulem 2019/11/18
\ULdepth=\dimen172
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty"
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg"
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\hyperref.sty"
Package: hyperref 2020-05-15 v7.00e Hypertext links for LaTeX

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty"
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pdftexcmds\pdftexcmds.sty"
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/infwarerr\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/kvsetkeys\kvsetkeys.sty"
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/kvdefinekeys\kvdefinekeys.sty"
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pdfescape\pdfescape.sty"
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hycolor\hycolor.sty"
Package: hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/letltxmacro\letltxmacro.sty"
Package: letltxmacro 2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/auxhook\auxhook.sty"
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/kvoptions\kvoptions.sty"
Package: kvoptions 2020-10-07 v3.14 Key value format for package options (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen173
\Hy@linkcounter=\count280
\Hy@pagecounter=\count281

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\pd1enc.def"
File: pd1enc.def 2020-05-15 v7.00e Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PD1 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PD1
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/intcalc\intcalc.sty"
Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/etexcmds\etexcmds.sty"
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count282
Package hyperref Info: Option `bookmarks' set `false' on input line 4338.
Package hyperref Info: Option `pdfnewwindow' set `true' on input line 4338.
Package hyperref Info: Option `colorlinks' set `true' on input line 4338.
Package hyperref Info: Option `final' set `true' on input line 4338.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4464.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4469.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4472.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4479.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4484.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks OFF on input line 4723.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \href on input line 4987.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count283
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 5076.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen174

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/bitset\bitset.sty"
Package: bitset 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/bigintcalc\bigintcalc.sty"
Package: bigintcalc 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
))
\Fld@menulength=\count284
\Field@Width=\dimen175
\Fld@charsize=\dimen176
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6347.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6352.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6355.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6362.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring ON on input line 6365.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6372.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6377.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6417.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6421.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\atbegshi-ltx.sty"
Package: atbegshi-ltx 2020/08/17 v1.0a Emulation of the original atbegshi packa
ge
with kernel methods
)
\Hy@abspage=\count285
\c@Item=\count286
\c@Hfootnote=\count287
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\hpdftex.def"
File: hpdftex.def 2020-05-15 v7.00e Hyperref driver for pdfTeX

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\atveryend-ltx.sty"
Package: atveryend-ltx 2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atvery packag
e
with kernel methods
)
\Fld@listcount=\count288
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count289

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/rerunfilecheck\rerunfilecheck.sty"
Package: rerunfilecheck 2019/12/05 v1.9 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/uniquecounter\uniquecounter.sty"
Package: uniquecounter 2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
86.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip58
)
\refchangenumber=\count290
\listchangenum=\count291
\c@figureplusone=\count292
\currentpage=\count293
\c@multimedia=\count294

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/endnotes\endnotes.sty"
Package: endnotes 2020-01-02 endnotes package
\c@endnote=\count295
\endnotesep=\dimen177
\@enotes=\write4
)
\reprintcolumnwidth=\dimen178
)
! Extra \endgroup.
\savedocument ->\endgroup 
                          \document@inithook \true@sw {}\UseOneTimeHook {beg...
l.4 \begin{document}
                    
? 
Class revtex4-1 Info: Unrecognized array package. Please update this document c
lass! (Proceeding with fingers crossed.) on input line 4.
Class revtex4-1 Info: cite was not loaded (OK!) on input line 4.
Class revtex4-1 Info: mcite was not loaded (OK!) on input line 4.
Class revtex4-1 Info: multicol was not loaded (OK!) on input line 4.

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.4 \begin{document}
                    
? 
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdftex.def"
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2020-09-24 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count296
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box72
)
(Test_JASA.aux)
\openout1 = `Test_JASA.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count297
\scratchdimen=\dimen179
\scratchbox=\box73
\nofMPsegments=\count298
\nofMParguments=\count299
\everyMPshowfont=\toks29
\MPscratchCnt=\count300
\MPscratchDim=\dimen180
\MPnumerator=\count301
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count302
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks30
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf-base.sty"
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.
)
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring ON on input line 4.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\nameref.sty"
Package: nameref 2019/09/16 v2.46 Cross-referencing by name of section

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/refcount\refcount.sty"
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/gettitlestring\gettitlestring.sty"
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count303
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 4.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 4.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 4.
Class revtex4-1 Info: Overriding lineo.sty, restoring output routine, on input 
line 4.
Class revtex4-1 Info: Line numbering not turned on yet on input line 4.
\openout3 = `Test_JASANotes.bib'.

Class revtex4-1 Info: Overriding \@LN@LLerror on input line 4.


Class revtex4-1 Warning: Assuming \noaffiliation for authors.

[1{C:/Users/Vianello/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msa on input line 15.


("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsa.fd"
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msb on input line 15.


("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsb.fd"
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+lasy on input line 15
.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\ulasy.fd"
File: ulasy.fd 1998/08/17 v2.2e LaTeX symbol font definitions
) [2] (Test_JASA.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 10135 strings out of 479768
 147106 string characters out of 2876561
 456149 words of memory out of 3000000
 26942 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 544329 words of font info for 64 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 92i,5n,98p,253b,332s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts
/cm/cmbx10.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr1
2.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmss12.pfb><C
:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmss8.pfb><C:/Program
 Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmssbx10.pfb>
Output written on Test_JASA.pdf (2 pages, 50132 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 38 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 6 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: That `JASA` class is built on top of `revtex4-1`.  That was a known issue and it is already fixed.  Updating `revtex4-1` should solve the problem

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik that might not help much if MikTeX no longer carry it.

Comment: Yes, I tried to install manually revtex4-1s from https://www.ctan.org/pkg/revtex4-1 and I tried to put the files at the right place (ther is no TDS file....)  in my localtexmf directory bu still I have the problem....However, I did notice that the issues boils down to having a "begindocument/before" printed on the top of my pdf file which is not so terrible, for a while. Anyway I think here there is a problem. The compiler tells me that: Class revtex4-1 Info: Unrecognized array package. Please update this document class etc......
lass! (Proceeding with fingers crossed.) on input line 52.

Comment: @daleif Oh, right, it's on `obsolete`. I forgot MiKTeX doesn't pick up those.

Comment: @mvs Indeed, CTAN doesn't store the TDS for packages marked obsolete.  Here's a link to the same TDS I sent to TeXLive: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o4zfkuzsx40j6o0/revtex4-1.tds.zip?dl=0 .  It printing `begindocument/before` is a bad sign: you'll need to have that fixed or more things will be wrong in your document.  Try updating your `revtex4-1` first

Comment: OK, now it works. I did notice that for some reason in my localtexmf I still had a version "r" (and not "s") of revtex4-1.cls. Maybe I made some mistake installing manually revtex4-1. Thanks. I have to say that this does not seem to be the way things should work....To whom should I point out this, for avoiding this hussle to other people? Maurizio.

Comment: @mvs To me :) (kind of).  The “most wrong” party here is the `JASA` class that uses `revtex4-1` which is clearly marked as obsolete: it should use `revtex4-2` instead.  That said, there was an update in LaTeX and I made a `revtex4-1` update (even if obsolete) to keep it working, but MiKTeX didn't pick that up because `revtex4-1` is obsolete.  Me and Mark, from APS plan to pack all three RevTeX versions in one single package, so in the future MiKTeX will pick up the `revtex4-1` along with `revtex4-2`.  That might take a while though...