# revtex4-1.cls not found in miktex2.9 in Windows 7

Tags: texstudio, revtex, compilation-error, miktex2.9

I have installed Miktex latest version today in a newly formatted Windows 7. Then tried to run a .tex file in Texstudio. That file starts with:

```
\documentclass[12pt,preprint,superscriptaddress,floatfix,showpacs]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  %Input what you want e.g., é, ł, a, ü
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}     %Output what you want e.g., é, ł, a, ü
\usepackage[british]{babel}  %Do hyphenation according to british english
\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}\linespread{1.05}  %Palatino font
\usepackage[scaled=0.86]{berasans}  % URL font that go well wtih palatino
%\usepackage[scaled=1.03]{inconsolata} %Monospace font
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}  %Hyperlinks (pink, green, blue)
\usepackage{graphicx} % Package to insert exteral figures
\usepackage[babel]{microtype}  %Improves text justification
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,bm,amsfonts,mathrsfs,bbm} %Useful math packages
\usepackage{xspace}  %Useful to add space in macros
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{color}
```

And then usual body follows. For your information, this file runs in other computers. But, in the above said pc it shows that revtex4-1.cls is not found.

I then tried to install revtex from Miktex console. It does not show any option.

[image]

I even started installing those packages shown in the image and then execute my .tex file. But again revtex4-1.cls is not found.

I searched here also, but have not found any such solution.

Kindly help.

***Note:*** I am not used to with the cmd and other commands / shortforms, so kindly write in an explanatory mode please. Thanks in advance.

***Solution / Partial Solution*** I just changed revtex4-1 to revtex4-2 in the documentclass command. And it runs. For details see the comments below, where daleif and UlrikeFischer solved it. Thanks to them.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/571200/3929, note that 4-1 is considered obsolete, users should use 4-2 nowadays

Comment: If I just change in my code, from {revtex4-1} to {revtex4-2} will it run?

Comment: @campa no that is not the problem here. miktex simply doesn't install this class as it is obsolete.

Comment: @aqm the easiest way to find out, is to try.

Comment: @campa, I have not updated it from the miktex console. This miktex is newly downloaded from proper site and installed in my pc. I just installed revtex related packages. In miktex console, update tab shows there is only one update: miktex-misc. That's why I have not updated it.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer I tried last two days. Even formatted my Windows7. And now tried to gather community knowledge from here.

Comment: Did you change to revtex4-2 in the documentclass command and try to compile?

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer it runs. I changed from 4-1 to 4-2. And it runs. Great. Thanks. :D

Comment: Thanks @daleif, you first mentioned it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MikTeX will not install things that are marked `obsolete` (https://ctan.org/pkg/revtex4-1?lang=en). `revtex4-1` has been superseded by `revtex4-2`. So you should be able to just change

```
\documentclass[...]{revtex4-1}
```

to

```
\documentclass[...]{revtex4-2}
```

and it will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Thanks, helpful pointer.