# File `revtex4-2.cls' not found

Tags: ubuntu, revtex, compilation-error

I am having this problem while compiling the latex file that says:

> File `revtex4-2.cls' not found. ^^M

where i'm using the command :

> \documentclass[aps, prl, twocolumn, amsmath, superscriptaddress,showkeys,showpacs]{revtex4-2}

I looked up to the same problem where 'revtex4-1' was not working but 'revtex4-2' was. That question is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/573304/revtex4-1-cls-not-found-in-miktex2-9-in-windows-7).

I am using 'TexStudio' in Ubuntu 20.04.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have the `revtex` package installed?

Comment: I hope so. I think TexStudio auto installs missing packages. Actually I didn't have to install any package manually before.

Comment: Which distribution do you have?

Comment: texstudio is only an editor. Which texsystem do you use and how old/new is it? (check the log-file it should tell you it at the begin)

Comment: if you have an older system you can probably just use 4.1 there isn't that much difference

Comment: I think it is TeX Live 2019/Debian.

Comment: revtex 4.2 is 2020 so you need to update or easier use revtex 4.1

Comment: revtex 4.1 is not working too.... Can you please tell me how to update?

Comment: you could install 4.1 through your linux  package manager eg apt if you don't have a full texlive 2019 installed, not sure which debian package it is in though you'd have to search.